# Cannot call variables on mount livewire component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

For some reason my livewire component cannot read the $blog variable even tho I can dd it fine, can't please help. For some reason I cannot call the variables on my blade.php file

```
Undefined variable: blog (View: E:\wamp64\www\atgs-cms\resources\views\livewire\blog\blog-post.blade.php)

Possible typo $blog
Did you mean $blog?
```

It gives me this error but I have a variable of $blog in the component class.
This is my component  class

```
class BlogPost extends Component
{
    public $blogId;
    public $blog;

    public function mount($blogId)
    {
        $this->blogId = $blogId;
        $this->blog = Blogs::select('*')->where('id',$blogId)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.blog.blog-post')->layout('layouts.blog');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the implicit route model binding like Laravel does. For example
redirect component

```
<td>
  <a href="{{ route('blog-component',['blog' => $item]) }}">Redirect</a>
</td>
```

web.php file

```
Route::get('/blog/{blog}',BlogComponent::class)->name('blog.show');
```

blog component, you have 2 ways to solve this:

1-

```
public $blog;

public function mount(Blog $blog)
{
   $this->blog = $blog;
}
```

2-

```
public Blog $blog;
```